# Animation Change Delay When Landing On Ground

Tags: unity, c#, physics, animation

I am working on a 2d platformer-like game in Unity. My problem is that when my player character jumps and lands back on the ground, there is a slight delay at times when transitioning to the player idle animation. **This is not due to exit time.** Instead, upon researching this topic, I found that my real problem lies in the Unity physics loop([FixedUpdate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html)).

`FixedUpdate`, as the name implies, is called a fixed amount of times, not every frame. My animator relies on a `Jumping` boolean to tell it whether or not to be in the jumping animation. In my code, the `Jumping` boolean is set to false when the player lands on the ground. This is handled by `OnCollisionEnter2D`, which runs on `FixedUpdate`.

This is were I think my problem lies:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {
        _isOnGround = true;
        _animator.SetBool("Jumping", false);
    }
}
```

I need to know whether or not the player is colliding with the ground, So I setup a tag. I need to find a way to constantly check whether or not I am colliding with the ground, So that I do not see an animation transition delay.

Any Ideas of how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that changing the rigidbody collision detection type to **continuous** helped remedy the delay. Although it still is there to an extent, this is the best solution I could find for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out Physics2D.OverlapArea. It takes a rectangle and checks if it is overlapping with another sprite. Here is some code I have been using that works well.

```
//Corners of the rectangle to check
 public var top_left : Transform;
 public var bottom_right : Transform;
 public var ground_layers : LayerMask;
 var grounded : bool;

 function FixedUpdate(){
     grounded = Physics2D.OverlapArea(top_left.position, bottom_right.position, 
   ground_layers);    
  }
```